# Scala Path Dependant Return Type Case Class Copy

Tags: scala

Having a brainfreeze on the following:

```
abstract class A {
  def withName(name: String): this.type
}

case class B(name: String) extends A {
  def withName(name: String): this.type = copy(name = name.reverse)
}

case class C(name: String) extends A {
  def withName(name: String): this.type = copy(name = name.toLowerCase)
}
```

Basically I want the methods in B and C to return the same type as themselves.

Comment: Unless sub-classes of A are mutable and actually mutate and return themselves inside `withName`, your signature is nonsensical. As per its signature (return type `this.type`) `withName`  can only return itself, but `withName` is at the same time supposed to change the name. Kind of a catch-22.

Comment: Yes I know it makes no sense because I'm saying, return me, but copy will always return a copy of me, but that's what I'm asking. I want B to return type B and C to return type C.

Comment: gzm0 has correctly summed up what I was trying to do. Thanks for all replies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can of course also use type members for the same thing:

```
abstract class A {
  type R <: A
  def withName(name: String): R
}

case class B(name: String) extends A {
  type R = B
  def withName(name: String): R = copy(name = name.reverse)
}
```

Comment: Now we're cooking on gas!

Comment: Actually it's "…with gas."

Answer (score 1):

Two possible solutions:

Cast:

```
abstract class A {
  def withName(name: String): this.type
}

case class B(name: String) extends A {
  def withName(name: String): this.type = copy(name = name.reverse).asInstanceOf[this.type]
}

case class C(name: String) extends A {
  def withName(name: String): this.type = copy(name = name.toLowerCase).asInstanceOf[this.type]
}
```

F-bounded polymorphism:

```
abstract class A[T <: A[_]] {
  def withName(name: String): T
}

case class B(name: String) extends A[B] {
  def withName(name: String): B = copy(name = name.reverse)
}

case class C(name: String) extends A[C] {
  def withName(name: String): C = copy(name = name.toLowerCase)
}
```

Comment: I knew both of those methods. I was hoping there was a nice path-dependent way to do it. I will give you an up-vote because you're answering my question "is there a better way to do it" by saying "no" :)

Comment: The version with a cast is really a subversion of the type system (or in other words, you are "lying"). `this.type` means the "type of this one instance", so the only correct thing to do is to return `this`. But here you return another instance and then cast it, effectively pretending that it is the same insatance when it's not.